# Commit CI build outcome into repository

Tags: azure-devops

I have 2 git repositories in Azure devops, 1 for my back-end app & 1 for my front-end app, I want that in the CI release process it should take the outcome from the front-end build & commit it to the back-end repository into the wwwroot folder;

The reason why I need this is because I want that the back-end developers should have the front-end build from within their code, so they should be able to debug the back-end code with the front-end UI within visual studio

I have already tried to use the copy files task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=vsts&tabs=yaml), but it don't do the job, either because I cannot seem to get the right target path, or because it also needs to be committed

Comment: This is not a good approach. A better approach would be to use submodules so that the front-end code can be built and debugged on-demand by the back-end developers.

Comment: @DanielMann The back-end developers have no reason to debug the front-end code, & it takes long to build the front-end, Why would they need to wait for the front-end build every time they want to debug the back-end

Comment: Then publish the front-end build outputs as a package and have it referenced in the back-end project as a dependency that can be restored by their toolchain.